# boost::interprocess::message_queue constructor failing

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

boost::interprocess::message_queue constructor failing when processes are run under different users.
To be more concrete. I'm creating message_queue in proc1. and trying to open the same message_queue from proc2 (another user).
Is it possible to make it working? Or I should find another way to synchronize my processes?

boost-1.52
OS: Windows 7 x86
Compiler: MSVC 2010

P.S. The code is trivial. And completely working if both processes was started from the same user.

P.P.S. This is a message box I've got. I could not call LastWindowError()...

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
Runtime Error (at 18:421):



External exception E06D7363.
---------------------------
ОК   
---------------------------
```

My code (of the Process2):

```
   void ipcMsg1(HWND hWnd) {
    util::MsgBox mb(hWnd, L"Sending Message1");
    try {
        mb.info(L"create mq");
        bipc::message_queue mq(bipc::open_or_create, plmqproto::g_mqName, plmqproto::g_mqSize, sizeof(int));
        mb.info(L"created");
        const int msg = plmqproto::g_mqMessage1;
        mq.send(&msg, sizeof(msg), 0);
        bipc::message_queue::remove(plmqproto::g_mqName);
    } catch(const bipc::interprocess_exception &ex) {
        mb.error(plcore::stringToWString(ex.what()));
        std::wstringstream ss;
        const unsigned long we = GetLastError();
        ss << L">1. GetLastError: " << we << std::endl;
        ss << L" " << plcore::GetWindowsErrorMessage(we); 
        mb.error(ss.str());
    } catch(const std::exception &ex) {
        mb.error(plcore::stringToWString(ex.what()));
        std::wstringstream ss;
        const unsigned long we = GetLastError();
        ss << L">2. GetLastError: " << we << std::endl;
        ss << L" " << plcore::GetWindowsErrorMessage(we); 
        mb.error(ss.str());
    } catch(...) {
        std::wstringstream ss;
        const unsigned long we = GetLastError();
        ss << L">3. GetLastError: " << we << std::endl;
        ss << L" " << plcore::GetWindowsErrorMessage(we); 
        mb.error(ss.str());
    }
}
```

So. I'm getting only "create mq" message box. and fail after that.

Boost upgrade did not helped.

Comment: What is GetLastError() returning?  My guess is '5'.